# Meteor template: What's the simplest way to check if a user is logged in?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts, meteor-helper

I'm using Meteor's accounts-ui.  Is there a way to check if the user is logged in on the template without writing custom helper code?

Pseudo code:

```
{{#if userIsLoggedIn }}
    You're logged in
{{/if}}
```

If not, what's the cleanest, most idiomatic way of doing it?

I only care about client-side here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Simple answer: check if the `currentUser` object exists.

```
{{#if currentUser }}
  You're logged in
{{/if}}
```

Yes, it is a default helper, no need to write anything else!

Comment: Great - so easy if you know :D

Comment: Note: to check in your javascript if the user is logged in you can use `if (Meteor.user())`

Comment: Is there a React-way of knowing this? `Meteor.user()` is too expensive to call when required by multiple components.

Comment: Sadly, no. React being independent from the Meteor ecosystem, I guess you'll have to either build that logic yourself or find a third party that did. Welcome to the world of modularity, my friend